# Confusing `__instancecheck__` print

Tags: python

I do something like this,

```
class MetaA(type):
  def __instancecheck__(self, obj):
    print('hello world')
    return super().__instancecheck__(obj)
```

```
class A(metaclass=MetaA):
  pass
```

```
a = A()
```

```
isinstance(a, A)
```

gives,

```
True
```

whereas,

```
isinstance(None, A)
```

gives,

```
hello world
False
```

why did it not print `hello world` the first time?

when I create another class,

```
class C(A):
  pass
```

and then,

```
a = C()
```

```
isinstance(a, A)
```

gives,

```
hello world
True
```

but,

```
isinstance(a, C)
```

gives,

```
True
```

why does it not print `hello world` sometimes?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949. Most of the answers explain metaclass inheritance.

Comment: ``type(a) is self`` holds for the cases that don't print.

Comment: If it is an exact type match `__instancecheck__` won't be called, python circumvents the check